# confluent_kafka python consumer.poll() function exits the entire code

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-python

I am referring to this [tutorial for kafka](https://towardsdatascience.com/kafka-in-action-building-a-distributed-multi-video-processing-pipeline-with-python-and-confluent-9f133858f5a0) which I have changed the video frames to image inputs. In my case, consumer.poll() does not return anything and breaks out of the code. In the docker terminal displays this:

```
kafka1    | [2023-01-10 07:21:30,719] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Dynamic member with unknown member id joins group kafka-cam in Empty state. Created a new member id rdkafka-f0ea3fd0-2eef-494d-bbe5-1acd9db067c4 and request the member to rejoin with this id. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka1    | [2023-01-10 07:21:30,721] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Preparing to rebalance group kafka-cam in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 0 (__consumer_offsets-24) (reason: Adding new member rdkafka-f0ea3fd0-2eef-494d-bbe5-1acd9db067c4 with group instance id None; client reason: not provided) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka1    | [2023-01-10 07:21:33,722] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Stabilized group kafka-cam generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-24) with 1 members (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)(kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

But it does not actually run the code below:

```
while True:
     print("entered")
     msg = consumer.poll(100) 
     print(msg)
     if msg == None:
         continue
```

as consumer.poll exits the entire code as a whole and does not run anything after that.

According to the printing statements I have added for testing purposes, msg should either return None or the value of whatever the consumer polls. However, it breaks out of the code.

```
python consumer.py 
Creating consumer thread...
Starting the consumer thread...
entered
```

As shown above, it prints entered but does not run the print(msg) after calling poll.

The poll function should only return None or msg, otherwise throw an exception. It should not break out of the code. Anyone experiencing this issue? I might be doing something wrong as this is the first time I am using kafka.

My Producer file:

```
from producer_config import config as producer_config
from confluent_kafka import Producer
import os
import concurrent.futures
import cv2
from utils import *
from glob import glob

class ProducerThread:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.producer = Producer(config)


    def publishImage(self, img_path):
        img = cv2.imread(img_path)
        print(img.shape)
        img_name = os.path.basename(img_path).split(".")[0]
        img_bytes = serializeImg(img)
        self.producer.produce(
            topic = "multi-cam-stream",
            value = img_bytes,
            on_delivery = delivery_report,
            timestamp = 0,
            headers = {
                "img_name": str.encode(img_name)
            }
        )
        self.producer.poll(0.5)
        return 


    def start(self, img_paths):
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(self.publishImage, img_paths)

        self.producer.flush() # push all the remaining msgs in the queue
        print("Finished")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    img_dir = "imgs/"
    img_paths = glob(img_dir + "*.JPG")
    producer_thread = ProducerThread(producer_config)
    producer_thread.start(img_paths)
```

Producer Config:

```
config = {
    'bootstrap.servers': '127.0.0.1:9092',
    'group.id': 'kafka-cam',
    'enable.auto.commit': False,
    'default.topic.config': {'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'},
}
```

My Consumer file:

```
import threading
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaError, KafkaException
from consumer_config import config as consumer_config
from utils import *
from pymongo import MongoClient
from dotenv import load_dotenv

import os
import base64
import requests
import json


class ConsumerThread:
    def __init__(self, config, topic, batch_size, model_api, db):
        self.config = config
        self.topic = topic
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.model_api = model_api
        self.db = db


    def read_data(self):
        consumer = Consumer(self.config)
        consumer.subscribe(self.topic)
        self.run(consumer,0)

    def run(self, consumer, msg_count):
        try: 
            coll = db.outputs
            imgs = []
            # msg = consumer.poll(2)
            # print(msg)
            while True:
                print("entered")
                msg = consumer.poll(timeout=3)
                # why did it skip after poll?
                print(msg)
                if msg == None:
                    print("msg is empty")
                    continue
                elif msg.error() is not None:
                    raise KafkaException(msg.error())
                elif msg.error() == None:
                    # msg.value() returns bytes
                    img_bytes = msg.value()
                    # img_bytes = base64.b64decode(img_bytes)
                    imgs.append(img_bytes)
                    print(len(imgs))

                    msg_count += 1
                    if msg_count % self.batch_size == 0:
                        print(len(imgs))
                        files = {
                            f"{_id}": img
                            for _id, img in enumerate(imgs)
                        }
                        # feed it to the model api
                        response = requests.post(MODEL_API, files=files)
                        results = json.loads(response.content)
                        for _id in files:
                            img_str = base64.b64encode(files[_id])
                            img = {
                                "image": img_str,
                                "result": results[int(_id)]
                                }
                            coll.insert_one(img)
                        
                        consumer.commit(asynchronous=False)
                        # msg_count = 0
                    elif msg.error().code() == KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
                        print('End of partition reached {0}/{1}'
                            .format(msg.topic(), msg.partition()))
                    else:
                        print('Error occured: {0}'.format(msg.error().str()))
                print(msg_count)
                
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Detected Keyboard Interrupt. Quitting...")
            pass
        
        finally:
            print("closing")
            consumer.close()

    def start(self, numThreads):
        for _ in range(numThreads):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.read_data)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_dotenv()
    topic = ["multi-cam-stream"]
    MODEL_API = os.environ["MODEL_API"]
    MONGODB_URI = os.environ["MONGODB_URI"]
    client = MongoClient(MONGODB_URI)
    db = client.smart_agriculture

    print("Creating consumer thread...")
    consumer_thread = ConsumerThread(consumer_config, topic, 4, MODEL_API, db)
    print("Starting the consumer thread...")
    consumer_thread.start(1)
```

Consumer Config:

```
config = {
    'bootstrap.servers': '127.0.0.1:9092',
    'group.id': 'kafka-cam',
    'enable.auto.commit': False,
    'default.topic.config': {'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'},
    'max.poll.interval.ms': 20000,
    'session.timeout.ms': 10000,
    'fetch.message.max.bytes': 10000000,
    'max.partition.fetch.bytes': 1000000
}
```

Utils.py:

```
import logging
import cv2
import json

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

def delivery_report(err, msg):
    if err:
        logging.error("Failed to deliver message: {0}: {1}"
            .format(msg.value(), err.str()))
    else:
        logging.info(f"msg produced. \n"
                    f"Topic: {msg.topic()} \n" +
                    f"Partition: {msg.partition()} \n" +
                    f"Offset: {msg.offset()} \n" +
                    f"Timestamp: {msg.timestamp()} \n")

def serializeImg(img):
    _, img_buffer_arr = cv2.imencode(".jpg", img)
    img_bytes = img_buffer_arr.tobytes()
    return img_bytes

def jsonify(img):
    return json.dumps(img)
```

Comment: Please show the rest of your Python code. Refer [mcve]. 'Or otherwise throws' - Have you tried adding try-except?

Comment: Consumers default to start and the end of the topic and wait for new events... So, are you actually producing anything?

Comment: @OneCricketeer It seems like my producer is not actually producing anything even though it seems to be correctly encoded and producer.produce does manage to run, however the console stops at `Acquired new producerId block ProducerIdsBlock(assignedBrokerId=1, firstProducerId=0, size=1000) by writing to Zk with path version 1 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)` and does not further mention the data that has been produce, hence I am probably not producing anything, but I can't seem to identify what went wrong...

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have added my Producer and Consumer files in the post, could you take a look at them and kindly let me know if you see anything I am doing incorrectly? Sorry for the inconvenience, I am pretty new to this, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Kafka has a default record limit of 1MB. How large are your images? Also, producer itself is thread safe, so you don't need a pool of them. Plus, you should consider using Kafka Connect Mongo sink

Comment: I'm certain that my images are not the issue as I am currently using 8 images as a test which totals up to around 105kB only. That's the reason why I couldn't figure out what went wrong. As for the producer is thread safe, I'm assuming u mean that I don't need to do this: `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()`. I did consider using Kafka Connect Mongo sink as well, but I haven't quite gotten to that point yet, hence the lack of development of the code. Thanks for the insight, I'm still searching up on my producer issue, please do let me know if you have an idea of the issue! Thanks!

Comment: Don't use an executor in the producer, correct. Start with a regular for loop. They try flushing within publishImage function... Add more print statements to debug further. Also, `delivery_report` and `serializeImg` are never defined, so this isn't your full code

Comment: Oh, thats right! I forgot to include my utils file where I used the functions u mentioned. Sorry for my mistake. As for the executor, I tried using a for loop and there seems to be a lot of errors, I'm working on that rn. I'll edit the post on the updated version when it works. Thanks for the help @OneCricketeer !! I've added my config files and also the utils file as well.